# When to offer co-authorship vs asking for feedback

Tags: writing, authorship, review-articles

I am quite new to this game and I am not sure how to ask people to be co-authors on a paper I have mostly written myself but that I think would get better  with someone else's input. When is a good strategy to offer a coauthorship and when should I simply ask for a feedback on the paper? This is somewhat of a review paper and I feel that it would be important to have some experts from the field. But regardless how should I decide when to offer a coauthorship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd ask for help. If said help turns out relevant, add a footnote thanking for it. If the help is in some way crucial (found and fixed a fatal flaw, suggested a (better) way to compute the results, suggested a relevant extension, ...) ask the helper if they want to be coauthors or just be thanked as above.

Answer (score 0):

Co-authorship depends on many factors, few of them are:

1. The authors who had worked with you together to achieve the results.
   Since this is your review paper, then co-authors may be them who had
   shared the knowledges to briefly summarize your findings to write
   the paper.
2. To get the proper feedback of any research work mostly
   depends on the methods, results and discussions. So you need to find
   few researchers' paper which has a good overlap with your findings.
   Then you can ask the most focused/ experienced/ renowned researcher
   out of them to get some feedback.
3. To increase the standard of the paper, you can ask well known
   scientists/ researchers who can reorganize your paper.